# Polars: efficiently get the 2nd largest element

Tags: python-polars, rust-polars

In polars, how do you efficiently get the 2nd largest element, or nth for some small n compared to the size of the column?

Comment: Can you add an example DataFrame along with the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`top_k`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.top_k.html) and slice the last row:

```
import polars as pl

np.random.seed(0)
df = pl.DataFrame({'col': np.random.choice(5, size=5, replace=False)})

out = df.top_k(2, by='col')[-1]
```

You could also [`filter`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.filter.html) with [`rank`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.rank.html), but this will perform a full sort, so it could be algorithmically less efficient:

```
out = df.filter(pl.col('col').rank(descending=True)==2)
```

Or with [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`argpartition`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html):

```
out = df[int(np.argpartition(df['col'], -N)[-N])]
```

Output:

```
shape: (1, 1)
┌─────┐
│ col │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 3   │
└─────┘
```

Input:

```
shape: (5, 1)
┌─────┐
│ col │
│ --- │
│ i64 │
╞═════╡
│ 2   │
│ 0   │
│ 1   │
│ 3   │
│ 4   │
└─────┘
```

###### timings:

1M rows

```
# top_k
39.3 ms ± 7.23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# filter+rank
54.6 ms ± 8.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

10M rows:

```
# top_k
427 ms ± 84.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# filter+rank
639 ms ± 102 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

100M rows

```
# top_k
4.04 s ± 411 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# filter+rank
6.12 s ± 244 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# argpartition
1.48 s ± 25.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

1B rows:

```
# top_k
??? (crashed)

# filter+rank
1min 6s ± 559 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

# argpartition
7.86 s ± 48.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Why is `top_k` so inefficient? I tried to run `.max()` on 1B elements and it took 2s. I ran `.top_k(1)` and `.top_k(2)` and both took 1min+. That's even slower than if I had run it in python.

Comment: `.top_k` can return duplicate values

Comment: @Test `top_k` should be relatively efficient if `n` is small, you don't have duplicates. When `n` increases it will start generating a larger intermediate while `filter`+`rank` should remain independent of `n`. I guess `top_k` might also depend on the number of columns.

Comment: Have you tried it on 1B+ elements? My experiment would seem to indicate that for some reason, `.top_k` isn't efficient for 1 or 2 elements compared to `.max` or a native implementation

Comment: @Test I actually tested a numpy solution ans it seems faster, but on the same timescale.

Comment: I'm getting 1min+ for polars. What are you getting for numpy?

Comment: `df[int(np.argpartition(df['col'], -N)[-N])]` gives me ~7s on 1B items

Comment: @Test can you try the numpy approach? It seems quite faster for 1B rows.

Comment: Yes, numpy seems much faster. ~10s for me. `top_k` is at least 4-8x that.